# What does the data sample (xi) means in z-score normalization?

Tags: normalization, z-score

Is $\mu_i$ computed by averaging over the entire features or by averaging over each feature respectively? Here is a snapshot I found from a journal article? Can anyone help to answer the above two question?

> Normalization operation is used to increase the classifier performance.  Frequent normalization methods are used after feature extraction.  However, in this study $z$-score normalization process is used.

> $\begin{eqnarray}z=\frac{x_i - \mu_i}{\sigma_i}\end{eqnarray}$

> Here, $x_i$ represents the data samples.  $\mu_i$ represents mean of the column and $\sigma_i$ represents the standard deviation of the same column.

Answer (score 0):

Does your article state what $i$ is here?  I'm assuming $i$ index the features.  In that case, if you look at the last sentence, assuming each feature is its own column (as is standard) and indexed by $i$, $\mu_i$ is the mean for feature $i$ (i.e. averaging over all the data for that feature).

So for example if you had two features, say, income and housing price, you'd simply compute the mean and standard deviation separately for income an then for housing price.  Next you subtract each income data point from the mean income and divide by the standard deviation for the income.  You'd then do the same for housing price, only using the housing price data.

I think part of the confusion here is that $x_i$ is really a vector of your data points, and not a single value, in which case it would probably be best represented by double-subscripts like $x_{ij}$, where $i$ is the feature, and $j$ is an individual measurement of element of feature $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 8,9,7,6,1,4,3,7,5 are your observation data and you want to normalise these values.
First you calculate the mean and standard deviation.

If you want to normalise the value '8' in your dataz then this is your `x_i`

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the OP's question about multiple features though.